# trying to return second lowest grade holders from the given series of inputs

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find the second smallest grade holders from the input data.
What is wrong with this code.

```
n = int(input())
lis=[] 
fin=[]
fin2=[]
for x in range(n):  #reading input data
    name=input()
    grade=float(input())
    lis.append([grade,name])
lis=sorted(lis)

for y in lis:      #finds second lowest grade holder
   if y > min(lis):
        fin.append(y)
        y=lis.index(y)
    lis.pop(y)
        break

for z in lis:     #finds all second lowest grade holders
   if z[0]==fin[0][0]:
       fin.append(z)


for xx in fin:
    fin2.append(xx[1])


fin2=sorted(fin2)
for zz in fin2:
    print(zz)
```

**Input:**

```
5
Harsh
20
Beria
20
Varun
19
Kakunami
19
Vikas
21
```

**Output:**

```
Kakunami
Varun
```

My Thinking :

I think there might be something wrong at second for loop which find the 
      second smallest grade. The issue is stated by the output. I am reading the 
      inputs in a nested list ("lis"), sorting them and then moving the second 
      highest grade holder to another list( "fin" in this case ) and them 
      comparing elements of this list to all the elements of the previous list ( 
      "lis") and adding elements which are equal to the new list ("fin2") and printing their holder name in sorted order.

Comment: `lis` is already sorted. I don't understand why you are iterating over it. `lis[1]` will be the element with the second smallest grade (since grade is the first item in each sublist). `list[1][1]` will be the name.

Comment: @DeepSpace, yeah, that'd be easier, but you'd need to check for duplicates with that approach as well, right?

Comment: yes i need to find duplicates too. And print them in sorted order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a sorted set of values of grades.`grades` set contains all grades in sorted manner without duplicates. So the second lowest grade will be 2<sup>nd</sup> element of the set, `grades[1]`. Then just iterate `lis` list to print second lowest values with duplicates.

```
n = int(input())
lis = []
fin = []
fin2 = []

for x in range(n):  # reading input data
    name = input()
    grade = float(input())
    lis.append([grade, name])

#create sorted set of grades.ex:{5,19,20,21}
grades = sorted(set(item[0] for item in lis))

for item in lis:
    if grades[1] == item[0]:
        print(item[1])
```